Migrating Azure RSA key pair to Google cloud KMS
Topic - Migrating AZURE RSA key pair to GCP KMS.
Currently I have RSA-HSM key in Azure vault with an operation to decrypt. I would like to migrate this key to GCP KMS. While exploring the documentation, I understood that KMS was more of a management tool and bit stuck on how to acheieve this. Any lead would be helpful here.
Additionaly, It is preferable to perform via terraform script. The idea is to upload the existing keys to KMS via terraform script.
Any leads would be much appreciated. Thanks.
